# Libreria SortableJS no se puede importar a mi proyecto

Tags: javascript, html

Cuando trato de importar la libreria a mi propio proyecto el script no esta funcionando, lo importe de la siguiente manera:

```
<head>
    <script src="scripts/codigo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

y me arroja el siguiente error:

Uncaught Sortable: el must be HTMLElement, and not [object Object]

y este

codigo.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined
at codigo.js:10:1

El código JS que se utiliza es el siguiente

```
function MostrarP() {
    document.getElementById("img-armado").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("img-comp1").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("textoarm").style.display = "block";
}

const lista = document.getElementById('img-comp1');


Sortable.create(lista, {
    swapThreshold: 1,
    animation: 150
});
```

¿Qué es lo que esta sucediendo o estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined at codigo.js:10:1

Se debe a que estás importando tu `script` antes que la librería `Sortable`, por tanto, cuando se ejecute tu `script`, `Sortable` no va a estar definido porque aún no se ha cargado.

Por otro lado, al poner tu script al inicio de la página, el script se va a ejecutar sin que el HTML se haya parseado, por tanto, cuando llames a `getElementById` vas a tener un error, porque aún los elementos no se han renderizado.

Para solucionar tus errores, lo primero que debes hacer es importar `Sorteable` antes de que tus propios scripts.

Para lo segundo, tienes 3 opciones:

1. Poner `<script src="scripts/codigo.js"></script>` al final del body.
2. Poner `<script defer src="scripts/codigo.js"></script>`
3. Mantener el `script` en el `head` pero modificar tu javascript para escuchar el evento `onload` y seleccionar el elemento sólo cuando el html se haya cargado. Algo así:

```
window.onload = function () {
    const lista = document.getElementById('img-comp1');

    Sortable.create(lista, {
        swapThreshold: 1,
        animation: 150
    });
}
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar y testear desde acá:

```js
const lista = document.getElementById('img-comp1');


Sortable.create(lista, {
    swapThreshold: 1,
    animation: 150
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>


<ul id="img-comp1">
    <li> Item 1</li>
    <li> Item 2</li>
    <li> Item 3</li>
    <li> Item 4</li>
    <li> Item 5</li>
    <li> Item 6</li>
    <li> Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, si funciono!